# Selenium not identifying Run as button in Cognos Report

Tags: java, selenium, testing, pytest, cognos

'Run as' button in Cognos Report is not recognized by Selenium and also we see some IBM copyright info at source view of the report.

I do not see any successful story on Cognos Report Automation Testing using Selenium. Could anyone clarify, whether its possible to identify 'Run as' button to export the report in CSV and Excel.

Note: I have tried with ID, CSS and xpath, none of the attributes are identified and no iframe is observed in the source view.

Please help us to fix it else i may need to drop the POC.

Comment: if you see it and its clickable by users then it should be clickable by selenium. you just need to make sure you click on the right place...

Comment: Agree with nafas. I know you tried using XPath but wanted to be clear Did you tried using Absolute XPath too @Ganesh Sundar?

Comment: Yes I tried with Absolute Xpath, CSS Selector etc. My only worry is . if owner of the page restricted to access that button through automation. Still can i try to get access to click the button and generate in CSV report.